# DNS log on Windows Server 2008

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, log-files

In a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, with DNS Server Role installed in a local network, can I read in some log which queries the network hosts have made? To obtain some list of the visited sites.

If not, which kind of informations can one retrieve from the logs? And where are the logs?

I did not succeed to find them from the Server Manager application.

Comment: You'd be better suited obtaining the logs from your firewall/router if you want to get visited sites...it would be more accurate than just DNS lookups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy/  Just right-click the DNS server, configure logging as required.  As Joeqwerty says it's not a pretty log but perfectly readable:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debug logging on the properties of the DNS server but honestly I don't think that's going to be of much value. The debug log isn't very user friendly.